# Seeing other computers on network with VirtualBox over NAT

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

One of my colleagues is running Windows 7 in VirtualBox 4.08 on her Mac, and needs to be able to connect to other computers on the same network within Windows.  Yet, whenever I look at the available networked computers in Windows on her system, all I see are her computer.  I can see her Windows 7 version from my Windows 7 system, but am unable to connect.

We are using a NAT configuration for the virtualized Network Adapter, since Bridge caused some issues with the software she was running in Windows.  Does anyone know why this is happening and, more importantly, how to fix it?

I can provide any additional information on request; I'm not really experienced with VirtualBox or her setup, so any lack of information is not intentional.
Thanks.

Comment: You will almost certainly need to switch over to bridged networking and figure out what the problem is what the other software.  Windows networking just doesn't work well across a NAT.

Comment: I figured as much.  I'll check back with the person who set up the configuration initially and see why NAT was chosen and which application experienced problems.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' network discovery isn't going to work across NAT, so you need to use bridged networking to get that working. You should be able to access servers by manually entering the IP address though, e.g. `\\192.168.0.10\`.